# Is there any way to generate resources names without Visual Studio Tool?

Tags: visual-studio, resources

Is it possible to generate(programmatically) resources names from aspx/ascx files without using the Visual Studio tool(Generate local resources)? I don't need to have .resx files, what I want is how to get full resoures names(I mean resource.property e.g.TextBoxResource1.ToolTip).

Answer (score 0):

See [Visual Studio - Tool to replace hard coded strings with resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553714/visual-studio-tool-to-replace-hard-coded-strings-with-resources).
and [Generate Local Resource for all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359634/generate-local-resource-for-all-pages)
In particular try http://resourcerefactoring.codeplex.com/