# Visual Studio 2015: Localize ASPX files: methods would be?

Tags: visual-studio

We need to localize an app that has hard coded strings across aspx and c# files.

This is a common need, so we expected to find tooling.

We tried resharper, but it turns out that for aspx files, this feature is essentially nonexistent.

What is the path forward?  (initially 60 aspx files, ultimately 200+)

I should add that we reviewed all known tools (below). In every case, at least one of the below is true:

- Does not work at all in visual studio 2015
- crashes right and left
- does not support aspx (mostly support .cs files only)

https://visuallocalizer.codeplex.com/

http://www.lingobit.com/extractor/c_sharp_extract_hardcoded_string.html

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/39ae29d3-81e1-43d4-9c48-fc9644869d84

[Visual Studio - Tool to replace hard coded strings with resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553714/visual-studio-tool-to-replace-hard-coded-strings-with-resources)

[Find all source hardcoded strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490974/find-all-source-hardcoded-strings)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution we have found so far is: Jinnee.Prelude 2015

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e71acd60-0f16-4adf-b398-18c4fa210916

Gives us localization in C# and static strings in ASPX. But still need to extract inline strings from ASPX by hand.

It crashed VS a couple of times, but VS is fast to restart (thanks to not having resharper installed). Overall it is a win. (Wish we had sources so we could enhance it further!)